# How to retrieve the const variable text

Tags: c#

I have a list of 1000 const variables declared in a class. I am storing the id while saving the record and while retrieving, I have to show the text. Example

```
public const uint ZenitStPetersburg = 100769;
```

So, while retrieving, I have to show ZenitStPetersburg

right now, I am doing switch case, Is there any elegent solution to retrieve the text?

Comment: You need to display that text that is the variable name?

Comment: Elegant? No. Why don't you store your data as a set of key-value pairs, like a dictionary?

Comment: exactly, the variable name

Comment: I would recommend investigating reflection (i.e. [Reflection in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx)). It can be used to retrieve members of a class including their names.

Comment: You could define an enum rather than constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1000 constants in a class? It seems to be a bad design.

That is what Enums are for.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    ZenitStPetersburg = 100769,
    ...
}
```

Then you get the string representation of it from value using something like this

```
string text = ((MyEnum)100769).ToString();//You're done
```

Or

```
string text = ((MyEnum)Enum.ToObject(MyEnum),100769).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, You saved my time. Otherwise, you would keep writing that ugly code and in this way, i did it in just 1 min

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, instead of variables, leverage a `Dictionary<uint, string>`:

```
private Dictionary<uint, string> _constants = new Dictionary<uint, string>
{
    { 100769, "ZenitStPetersburg" }
}
```

and then just look it up in the dictionary:

```
var val = _constants[uintValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you own the source, why don't you try using an `enum` instead?  Something like this:

```
public enum Code : uint
{
    ZenitStPetersburg = 100769,
    ....
}
```

You can then easily get the name by doing a `.ToString()` on the enum variable.  Like this:

```
Code code = Code.ZenitStPetersburg;
string name = code.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should implement a `Dictionary<uint, string>`

```
public IDictionary<uint, string> CodeStringDictionary;
```

Then you can do:

```
if (CodeStringDictionary.ContainsKey(code))
   return CodeStringDictionary[code];
```